# Error installing gmrun via apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, apt

```
$ sudo apt-get install gmrun
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gmrun is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up monodoc-base (2.4.4~svn151842-1ubuntu4) ...

Processing triggers for monodoc-base ...
/usr/bin/update-monodoc: line 3: [: argument expected
generating monodoc search index...
/usr/bin/update-monodoc: line 9: monodoc: command not found
dpkg: error processing monodoc-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of monodoc-http:
 monodoc-http depends on monodoc-base; however:
  Package monodoc-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing monodoc-http (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 monodoc-base
 monodoc-http
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: (Is posting this enough, of should I add "Can you help me find what's the problem?" to make this a question?)

Comment: Output of `apt-cache policy gmrun monodoc-base monodoc-http` please. Also what version? Output of `lsb_release -a`? At first sight, this looks like it might be a bug.

Comment: Maybe take this to that Ubuntu forum?

Comment: It has nothing to do with gmrun, it has no dependencies for the monodoc-base package. It seems a previous installation or upgrade has not completed successfully. One of the installation scripts of monodoc-base is failing. The current version of monodoc-base is 2.6.7-3ubuntu1, so I guess you have an older ubuntu release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look like gmrun is any part of the problem or solution.

It looks more like something got buggered in the latest update of `monodoc-base` that results in it remaining unconfigured, which in turn means that `monodoc-http` can't be properly configured because it's missing a dependency.

According to that output, `gmrun` itself is already installed.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question.